# opencart, the defined discount is ignored (or not applied)

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, e-commerce, opencart

I setted up a discount for a product, like this:

[image]

But then in the shopping cart is never added:

[image]

any idea?

Comment: what`s your need say clearly..do you want to remove discount in shopping cart? else add discount in cart page?

Comment: you need to login as the customer first for the discount to be applied.

Comment: @DevZer0 Hi! thanks for replying, i am logged in and i have the same customer group that this product discount (default). Any idea?

Comment: @VIVEK-MDU I want to apply a discount for a specific product

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet..I think it may be useful http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=100789 and also check it out...http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=817

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opencart discounts are attached with user groups, in order for the discount to be applied you need to be signed in to the system using the customer email and password.

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet make sure the user your logged in is in the same group as the user you group you created the discount for

Comment: yes, user is logged in and discount group and customer group matchs

Comment: Also discounts are designed for purchasing multiple units of a product, and you should set a priority of at least 1.  If you are allowing a discount for a quantity of 1, you should use the special tab instead.